# Apache Kylin VS Arcadia data

Tags: kylin

Can anyone elaborate difference between apache kylin and Arcadia data?

Which is better in terms of support,functionality,ease of use,fetaures,file format,etc.

Answer (score 0):

I only have Kylin experience, which is an open source OLAP for Hadoop engine, with many adoptions in domains like the Internet, manufacturing, retails, etc.

Kylin can run on mainstream Hadoop versions which make its installation and management much easier. Kylin doesn't provide visualization feature, but you can connect it via ODBC/JDBC from many BI tools like Tableau, MSTR, Superset and more.

All the file formats the Hive supports can be fed into Kylin, like Text, Sequence, Parquet, JSON.

An important point is, Kylin is open source, it is free of charge, and you can customize it with your own requirements. To get support, you can send the question to its mailing list and there will be the response. To get professional service, you can contact Kyligence Inc.